# Enforce git merge.ff false on server side hook

Tags: git, merge

Our git workflow mandate that we always create a merge commit, even when it's a fast forward merge (simplify history reading without resorting to rebase).

While conventions are good ("please run 'git config -add merge.ff false'"), I want to enforce that kind of logic on our git server using a hook. I've tried to think about the logic and got stuck. Any clue on how to implement that kind of logic? Any ready-made scripts?

Comment: You should provide a few more details. I assume this convention is relevant for a `master` and/or `dev` branch? For which branches do you want to enforce merge commits?

Comment: @Zeeker It has to do with our git workflow - we're a large software house (multiple teams) and use the merge workflow. We have large outstanding branches that constantly merge from and to master. The merge.ff false parameter is an attempt to bring some sanity into our git history and subsequent merge processes by enforcing that master is always the "first parent" in any merge to master.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in hooks/update:

```
if [[ "$1" = "refs/heads/master" ]]
then
  if [[ $(git log --oneline $2..$3 --no-merges --first-parent | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]]
    then 
      exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: what do you think would be the effect of running this on all branches, not just master? Will it harm normal processing?

Comment: @RanBiron You probably do not want it on all branches; at some point someone has to do some work. What you might want is that all you environments should only have merges such as as production, staging, testing, etc. If this is the case, I would name all these "special" branches `env/*`, and then run the hook for master and the special branches.